# Error messege when running 'jekyll build' command on cloud 9

Tags: github, jekyll, cloud9-ide

I am a dev student and am having issues with Jekyll. Everytime I run a "jekyll build" command from my cloud 9 terminal I get the following messege:

Liquid Exception: Included file '_includes/archive_post.html' not found in source/404.markdown
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  Included file '_includes/archive_post.html' not found

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The error message is clear `_includes/archive_post.html` is not exists.

Comment: Are you inside your "jekyll-blog" folder? For example: `jekyll new myblog` and then `cd myblog` and then `jekyll build`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the file that is causing your issue:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mema82/mema82.github.io/feature/jekyll-theme/source/404.markdown

This file references archive_post.html which is non-existent. If you remove this file, or just remove the code referencing the missing file, Jekyll build should run successfully.